# Является ли изменение vptr атомарной операцией

Tags: c++

Скажите, пожалуйста, является ли изменение vptr (например - в деструкторе) атомарной операцией?

Comment: Нет, ничего об ароматности сказать нельзя. Наличие переменной vptr вообще не гарантированно стандартом (теоретически, возможны другие реализации виртуальных вызовов). Считайте, что не атомарная.

Comment: Обычно является. Однако не понятно, к чему такой вопрос. Это случаем не проблема XY? По идее, меняется оно или нет - вас волновать вообще не должно, так как в этот момент не должно быть никаких вызовов виртуальных функций.